# R Beginner: MSE returning NaN

Tags: r

I've coded it wrong somewhere because I get NaN for the MSE's. But I cannot for the life of me figure out where I went wrong. Everything in the first chunk of code was given to me as being true (besides n, H, j, & dtrain). {m = 50 is the size of the test dataset}. I was then told that the training data should have size n = 50; and to fit the linear models & find the MSE's for OLS, Ridge, & Lasso.

```
> library(glmnet)

> library(ISLR)

> set.seed(2018)

>m = 50

>**n = 50**

>p = 45

>rho = 0.7;

>Sigma = matrix(rho, p, p);

>diag(Sigma) = 1;

>X= MASS::mvrnorm(m, rep(0, p), Sigma);

>**H= MASS::mvrnorm(n, rep(0,p), Sigma);**

>beta0 = 10;

>num_nonzero = 45;

>beta = c(rep(1, num_nonzero), rep(0, p-num_nonzero));

>y = beta0+X%*%beta+rnorm(m);

>**j = beta0+H%*%beta+rnorm(n);**

>dtest = data.frame(y, X)

>**dtrain = data.frame(j, H)**
```

### OLS

```
fit.lm <- lm(j ~ ., data = dtrain)

pred.lm <- predict(fit.lm, dtest)

mean((pred.lm - dtest$j)^2)
```

### RIDGE

```
train.mat <- model.matrix(j ~ ., data = dtrain)

test.mat <- model.matrix(y ~ ., data = dtest)

grid <- 10 ^ seq(10, -2, length = 100)

fit.ridge <- glmnet(train.mat, dtrain$j, alpha = 0, lambda = grid, thresh = 1e-12)

cv.ridge <- cv.glmnet(train.mat, dtrain$j, alpha = 0, lambda = grid, thresh = 1e-12)

bestlam.ridge <- cv.ridge$lambda.min

bestlam.ridge

pred.ridge <- predict(fit.ridge, s = bestlam.ridge, newx = test.mat)

mean((pred.ridge - dtest$j)^2)
```

### LASSO

```
fit.lasso <- glmnet(train.mat, dtrain$j, alpha = 1, lambda = grid, thresh = 1e-12)

cv.lasso <- cv.glmnet(train.mat, dtrain$j, alpha = 1, lambda = grid, thresh = 1e-12)

bestlam.lasso <- cv.lasso$lambda.min

bestlam.lasso

pred.lasso <- predict(fit.lasso, s = bestlam.lasso, newx = test.mat)

mean((pred.lasso - dtest$j)^2)
```

Comment: Are you able to fit the linear models, i.e., do they return coefficients, std errors, etc?

Comment: Yes, when I use `summary(fit.lm)`, it gives coefficients, residuals, std errors and etc.

Comment: I noticed that your test matrix is dtest = data.frame(y, X), but you call mean((pred.lm - dtest$j)^2).
I think you should refer to dtest$y

Comment: That seems to have been the problem, though I could have sworn I had tried that earlier. Thank you so much for your help!